# I removed the run directory of /var/run on debian

Tags: terminal, debian

Can anyone tell me how I can undo a sudo rm -r /var/run mistake?

I can't use sftp and mysql now.

Comment: @BlueNovember: I'd edited that over on stackoverflow ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988866/help-i-removed-the-run-directory-of-var-run-on-debian-closed ).. 
, deleted here before noticing your question .. sorry for breaking the context. I figured the people on serverfault were most likely to have been in this "pit of doom" situation.

Comment: Ah, hence the confusion. Comment removed. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can... reinstall debian!

There's a reason you should be careful with anything starting with "sudo rm", and this is it :P

Comment: sudo rm -r, actually.

Comment: -f especially, but when you're deleting ANYTHING as root you should be bloody careful :P

Comment: You can *always* reinstall, but I personally would go to a lot of drudge work to avoid it...

Comment: You can fix things like this by reinstalling, but you can also dive in and try and put it all back together. You'll learn alot more about your system that way, and be motivated never to ever make that mistake again.

Comment: yp, try mykhal's answer. I don't think you need to reinstall like if you had to learn a lesson?!?!

Answer (score 8):

reinstalling debian is not necessary. in /var/run are stored temporary pid files.. just try if restart of broken services works, if not, do `dpkg -S /var/run` to see, which packages installed some subdirectories there (`dpkg -L <PACKAGENAME> | grep /var/run`), eventually you might want to try `dpkg-reconfigure <PACKAGENAME>`. then restart services (`/etc/init.d/... restart`) or entire debian.

Comment: See now, this is what happens when you know how your package manager works...

Comment: This is so much easier than re-installing the whole OS and worked for me.  Also, I had SELinux running in enforcing and had to run a restorecond as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simular problem, i must have removed this directory; and received :

```
Can't open /var/run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?
```

When running

```
at -m now -f ./run_my_file
```

I was able to fix it remaking the directory and restarting the atdeamon (atd)

```
sudo mkdir /var/run
sudo atd
```

Goodluck, we all make mistakes :)

ps. probably not the most solid-proof solution, but it worked !

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir /var/run
```

If something complains about a subdirectory missing, create it in the same way.  But packages are supposed to be robust against that now, because `/var/run` can be on a temporary file system.  Worst case, reinstall the package in question.